# Angular acceleration from torque and radius

Tags: torque, rotation, angular-velocity

The story is about wheel. I have a wheel and I need to know it's actual angular velocity(which doesn't mach `Vcar_longitudal / r`). What I have access to is torque input into wheel and wheel radius. I need to get wheel's actual angular velocity, to do it I just need to obtain wheel's angular acceleration and apply it to it's angular velocity.
Thanks! ;)

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://physics.info/rotational-kinematics/) and maybe add more substance to your question.

Comment: Well, I can't find a way to express my needed value from there, because there doesn't seem to be anything releated to torque...

Comment: Torque is related to angular speed analogously to the relation between force and velocity: $\tau = m \dot{\omega}$

Comment: rmhleo, what is the $m$ value? Is it mass?

Comment: Yes, it's mass, analogous to the force expression.

Comment: @rmhleo , but how would you relate this to the car in this case? Wheel gets torque from engine. How do you calculate it's angular velocity?

Comment: @rmhleo http://www.asawicki.info/Mirror/Car%20Physics%20for%20Games/Car%20Physics%20for%20Games.html - if you scroll down to the topic "Torque on the driver wheels", could you tell me if it is kinda correct in this link?:)

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have a mistake above, where I put mass, it should be moment on inertia $I=mR^2$ so $\tau = I \dot \omega$ and $R$ would be the wheel radius in your case.

Comment: @Adrians_Netlis you should consider writing an answer to your own question so the community can vote on it and read it. If you accept it as the answer you will also earn reputation. I will remove my comment with a mistake. Can you let me know when I can remove it?

Comment: @rmhleo so I did it, but I have no idea how to use mathematical formating.

Comment: It's OK I edited it for you. You can write here LaTeX equations and the interpreter can process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to some hints from rmhleo and a tutorial link I found I've got an answer. So I can express angular velocity from torque putten on tire following to those steps:

- Get momentum of inertia for wheel which is expressed like so: $I = mR^2$
  where $m$ = wheel mass, $R$ = wheel radius and $I$ = momentum of inertia.
- Obtain angular acceleration from torque and inertia: $\dot \omega= \tau / I$ where $\tau$ is the torque that wheel receives.
- Add angular acceleration to angular velocity.